# setMinFaceSize of MobileVision does not work

Tags: android, computer-vision, face-detection

I am building an app that requires a high speed landmark processing. Thus I tried to increase the setMinFaceSize to increase speed aswell.  But it seems to have no effect even if I choose values like 0.9 (=only detect faces, whose with is 90% of the image). Did anybody implement this successfully?

The builder of my FaceDetector looks like this:

```
FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(this)
                .setTrackingEnabled(false)
                .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
                .setMinFaceSize(0.5f)
                .build();
```

Can anybody help me? If you need further code, please let me know.

If anybody has experience with the FaceDetector of Google, please have a look at this question [aswell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59343628/face-detector-mobile-vision-speed-not-increased-with-smaller-bitmap/59343702?noredirect=1#comment104884789_59343702).